# java jdk replace native class-file

Tags: class, replace, native, java

I have `ImageView.class` how to get the program to use it instead of the native [javax.swing.text.html.ImageView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/ImageView.html)?

```
javax.swing.text.html.ImageView map = new javax.swing.text.html.ImageView(); //does not work
```

I was told that it is necessary to use `ClassFileTransformer` and `ClassLoader`, but I can not find a working examples

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you really want to do is to...

1. Extend `HTMLEditorKit` and override `getViewFactory()`
2. Have it return a class that extends `HTMLEditorKit.HTMLFactory`
3. In that class, override `create()` to return your custom view for <img> and `super.create()` otherwise

Like this:

```
class MyImageKit extends HTMLEditorKit {
    private static final MyImageFactory myFactory = new MyImageFactory();

    public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
        return myFactory;
    }

    static class MyImageFactory extends HTMLFactory {
        public View create(Element elem) {
            Object type = elem.getAttributes()
                              .getAttribute(StyleConstants.NameAttribute);
            if(type == HTML.Tag.IMG) {
                return new MyImageView(elem);
            } else {
                return super.create(elem);
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyImageView extends ImageView {
    MyImageView(Element elem) {
        super(elem);
    }

    protected void setPropertiesFromAttributes() {
        super.setPropertiesFromAttributes();
        try {
            ImageView.class.getDeclaredField("vAlign").set(this, new Float(0.75f));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I do not need it. I need to replace the native class to another class

Comment: http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/javax/swing/text/html/ImageView.java.html. Lines 258-267. There is no way to set Align = .75 f; or other - this is my problem

Comment: You could override `setPropertiesFromAttributes()` and use reflection to set `vAlign = 0.75f`.